# Scraping Prices from Kayak

Tags: python, selenium

I am really having a really hard time **scraping** flight prices from kayak with the following xpath using selenium. It just return a blank list when I run "pries". below is what I am using

```
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import smtplib

chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Documents/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

kayak = ('https://www.kayak.com/flights/JFK-SFO/2021-12-25/2022-01-03?sort=bestflight_a')

driver.get(kayak)

sleep(randint(10,20))

xp_prices = '//a[@class="booking-link whisky-booking-link"]/span[@class="price option-text"]'

prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xp_prices)

print(prices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple _ in  booking-link and don't use sleep use webdriver wait instead.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
kayak = 'https://www.kayak.com/flights/JFK-SFO/2021-12-25/2022-01-03?sort=bestflight_a'
driver.get(kayak) 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[46]/div[3]/div/button'))).click()
xp_prices = '//a[@class="booking-link "]/span[@class="price option-text"]'
prices = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,xp_prices)))
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs

```
$281
$302
$285
$289
$293
$302
$302
$306
$306
$306
$309
$313
$326
$346
$348
```